# Angular Bind variable to a hashmap with value of type string

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular2-databinding

I am trying to bind a variable which contains the date and time to a key value pair within `Component A`. I can see in the console the value of `currentDate`, but when I try to bind the variable to the `value` of `key = currDate` I get an error message stating that the variable is undefined.

[image: Undefined variable]

[image: Console Log]

Essentially, I would want to replace the part where it says `undefined` with something like `Friday May 21 11:38:19`

[image]

**Component A - ComponentA.ts**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { service } from '../../..common/service';


... Some Code...

@Component({
   selector: 'ComponentA',
   styleUrls: ['./ComponentA.css'],
   templateUrl: './ComponentA.html'
})

export class ComponentA {


... Some Code ...

currentDate: any;

plotDesc: { [key:string]: string } = {
     currDate: `The number of open requests since <div *ngIf="currentDate">${this.currentDate.data.date}</div>`
};

constructor(private sw: Service){ }

... Rest of Code ...
```

Comment: Where are you setting  `currentDate ` ?  As i can see on your code is you are using undefined property as an object. Also console seams to talk about promise but your code does not seams to point any Promise. You should consider adding https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Please post more code... or at the least don't pollute with `...Some code...`, ideally something reproducible.

Comment: I can't upload the code since it is privately owned. `currentDate` is an object that feeds data from a list of systems doing so by subscribing and saving the data in the from of a JSON response. `currentDate.data.date` contains the date/time data that I need. I have several methods that take care of this.